# angular2 multi language implementation

Tags: angular

I have service for multilanguage.

```
    import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { TRANSLATIONS } from './translations'; // import our opaque token

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {
  private _currentLang: string;

  public get currentLang() {
    return this._currentLang;
  }

  // inject our translations
  constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATIONS) private _translations: any) {
  }

  public use(lang: string): void {
    // set current language
    this._currentLang = lang;
  }

  private translate(key: string): string {
    // private perform translation
    let translation = key;

    if (this._translations[this.currentLang] && this._translations[this.currentLang][key]) {
      return this._translations[this.currentLang][key];
    }

    return translation;
  }

  public instant(key: string) {
    // public perform translation
    return this.translate(key);
  }
}
```

So, this works for component, which I select. But after go to another component and come back the language is set default value.

maybe remember selected language in localStorage? Does anybody have a good idea how to remember selected language?

Comment: Where do you declare the provider for this service?

Comment: I declare it in the app.module

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks like mine in a small project, so I'm going out on a limb here. Please, if this is correct, add the essential code from you components in your question, so other users can understand :)

But in your translate service you set the current language which can be seen from the code you provided:

```
  public get currentLang() {
    return this._currentLang;
  }
```

This service is then injected in the component, I have named it `_translateService` So just in your OnInit methods you check the current chosen language. It should look something like this:

```
this.selectLang(this._translateService._currentLang);
```

The selectLang method, which is also fired when user chooses a language option.

```
selectLang(lang: string) {
    this._translateService._currentLang = lang; // if user makes choice on some component, the new chosen language is pushed to service
    this._translateService.use(lang); // the method in your service
    this.refreshText(); // method that updates the content to current language
}
```

Hope this helps, and as said, add the `selectLang`-method (or the similarly named) in case you have used something like this in your app. And as a reference, this is the example I have used, and I suspect you have too:

### [Simple language translation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1)

Comment: Vahe, did this answer help you? :)